# WMS Server Imagery not exporting to pdf

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, wms, pdf

I'm creating a map in ArcMap 10.6 and I'm having trouble exporting it to a PDF.

Everything exports fine to PDF except for some SPOT imagery that I've loaded through a WMS Server. The imagery displays in the data frame in ArcMap but, when I export to PDF, the imagery does not get exported although all other layers export perfectly.

I've also loaded the mxd into ArcMap 10.3 and the same problem occurs.

Has anyone found a way to export WMS layers to pdf through ArcMap 10.6 or 10.3?

Comment: Does the WMS support pdf output

Comment: @nmtoken Yep. The WMS supports PDF output

Comment: @nmtoken Sorry. I figured this out. It had to do with the export settings. You did not have enough information from my original question to provide an answer. Apologies for that - I honestly didn't even consider that it might be my Ratio and JPEG Quality being set too high; I thought they could only be set too low

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright: I've figured this out. It has to do with the settings.

I was exporting my map with high resolution settings

- Resolution: 300 dpi
- Ratio: 1:1
- JPEG Quality: 100

This led to the output PDF being exported without the WMS layer (imagery). However, with the settings set to:

- Resolution: 300 dpi
- Ratio: **1:2**
- JPEG Quality: **85**

Everything exports properly and the image from the WMS layer is included in the output.